# Acceleration of bodies

Tags: acceleration, collision

Whenever when there is collision or when there is continued movement during contact we assume there is only continued acceleration and no other type of motion. We use this assumption to find various values like force and KE. What is the basis of this assumption?

Comment: Newton's laws of motion.

Comment: The laws do not say there can only be acceleration during movement and coillision.Or do they?

Comment: The only explanation that I can think of here is that the momentum of the bodies keeps varying after their collision, and hence from Newtons second Law, there is a force and hence the continued acceleration!

Comment: But how is there a linear decrease in momentum always?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "continued movement" and "continued acceleration"? And in the process, can you explain what you mean by "no other type of motion"?

Answer (score 0):

Are talking about Newtonian (Classical) mechanics - Physics I and II? if so, in that case all you need are Conservation of Energy and Conservation of Momentum. You ignore external forces.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer to the question. Can you expand on this answer and in the process address the OP's question about "continued acceleration"?